# Infinite loop error with publish_post and wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress, hook

I got the infinite loop error. I require to insert the post in German language when the post is created for default English language. 
I used publish_post action hook for catch the english posting event. But the publish_post hook is also executed by wp_insert_post() fucntion while creating the German post. So the infiniter error occured. Could anyone help ? Thank you. Below is the code i have used.

```
  add_action( 'publish_post', 'save_in_all_sites'  );

  function save_in_all_sites( $post_id ){

    global $sitepress;

         $my_post = array(
         'post_title'    => $post_title,
         'post_content'  => $post_content,
         'post_status'   => $post_status

         );

        $def_trid = $sitepress->get_element_trid($post_id);

        $ru_post_id1 = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        // insert the post in German language 

          $sitepress->set_element_language_details($ru_post_id1, 'post_post', $def_trid, 'de');

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work to remove the hook right before you wp_insert_post and then add it back right after.

Example

```
remove_action( 'publish_post', 'save_in_all_sites'  );
$ru_post_id1 = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
add_action( 'publish_post', 'save_in_all_sites'  );
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the code for english language ? is it `$def_trid` ? if yes then you are setting both english and german languages to `element_language_details` so when you get it, it returns you everything that is in english and german language trying setting these up separately with separate columns in your database too.

Comment: No it is not related to language issue. Idea is when i insert the post in English language(default). The publish_post hook is called so save_in_all_sites function is called. while i called wp_insert_post inside save_in_all_sites function the publish_post hook is called. I do not want to call the publish_post hook by wp_insert_post. Hope it is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: try writing the code to store german language in another function and then call it to get the value. I think you have both piece of codes under publish_post hook so no matter what whenever that hook will run it will run both the functions/methods or any code which is under that hook, so try separating the methods. Hope this will solve it.